# Keyboard input bug when 3 keys are pressed

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

Im having a problem in my code when 3 keys are pressed at the same time.
When I press

- Up + Right + Space: moves and the object fires
- Up + left + Space: moves but doesn't fire
- Down +Right + Space: moves but doesn't fire
- Down + Left + Space: moves but doesn't fire
- All other 2 key combinations are fine.

here is my code:

```
if (newkbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
    player.MoveFwd();
else if (newkbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
    player.MoveBkwd();
else
    player.StopMoving();

if (newkbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
    player.TurnLeft();
else if (newkbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
    player.TurnRight();
else
    player.StopTurning();

if (newkbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
    player.Fire();
```

Comment: Using the link that Haedrian provided, I found that my Dell laptop could not handle 3 keys when Left and Up are pressed. My Logitech wireless keyboard seems to be able to handle any 6 keys being pressed simultaneously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather basic problem - but does the keyboard support having more than 3 keys at the same time? "Ghosting" as its called is not unheard of in older keyboards:

https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx

Are you 100% sure its your code?

Comment: Im not sure, my keyboard is a dell L100 and I tried it on different keyboards and I got the same issue. But how come It works for UP+Right+Space ?

Comment: That article has an applet at the top, see if it can detect those 3 presses. Its to do with the construction of the keyboard - that link will explain.

Comment: For instance my keyboard doesn't support up-left-space but the others you described work.

Comment: Oh yea that's weird I think thats my issue. Is there any way I can fix that ?

Comment: Its a keyboard hardware issue. The only way to 'fix' it is to change the keyboard. Most gaming keyboards would probably work for example (since they're designed against that sort of thing). You might need to change the key combinations your application supports otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with your keyboard(Some Microsoft keyboards, for example have similar issues); just to be on the safe side, try another keyboard.